# Extract Maximum Likelihood for AR(2) model

Tags: r, time-series, maximum-likelihood, autoregressive

I created the AR(2) model you can see below:

```
# y(t)=0.1+0.5y(t-1)+0.1y(t-2)+u(t), with u(t)~N(0,1)
y.matrix <- matrix(rep(0,200),200) # number of data 200
c=0.1
ph1=0.5
ph2=0.1

for(i in 3:200)
{
 y.m[i] = 0.1 + ph1*y.m[i-1] + ph2*y.m[i-2] + rnorm(1, mean=0, sd=1)
}
```

Im new in these things in R language and i have study some articles about Maximum Likelihood for AR models.
I read the following process from another question :

```
## Simulate Arima
y <- arima.sim(n = 250, list(ar = 0.3, ma = 0.7), mean = 5)
plot(y)

## Optimize Log-Likelihood for ARIMA

n = length(y) ## Count the number of observations
e = rep(1, n) ## Initialize e

logl <- function(mx){

  g <- numeric
  mx <- matrix(mx, ncol = 4)

  mu <- mx[,1] ## Constant Term
  sigma <- mx[,2] 
  rho <- mx[,3] ## AR coeff
  theta <- mx[,4] ## MA coeff

  e[1] = 0 ## Since e1 = 0

  for (t in (2 : n)){
    e[t] = y[t] - mu - rho*y[t-1] - theta*e[t-1]
  }

  ## Maximize Log-Likelihood Function 
  g1 <-  (-((n)/2)*log(2*pi) - ((n)/2)*log(sigma^2+0.000000001) - (1/2)*(1/(sigma^2+0.000000001))*e%*%e)

  ##note: multiplying Log-Likelihood by "-1" in order to maximize in the optimization
  ## This is done becuase Optim function in R can only minimize, "X"ing by -1 we can maximize
  ## also "+"ing by 0.000000001 sigma^2 to avoid divisible by 0
  g <- -1 * g1

  return(g)

}

## Optimize Log-Likelihood
arimopt <- optim(par=c(10,0.6,0.3,0.5), fn=logl, gr = NULL,
                 method = c("L-BFGS-B"),control = list(), hessian = T)
arimopt
```

Im trying to *adjust this process to my AR(2) model which is y(t)=0.1+0.5y(t-1)+0.1y(t-2)+u(t)* as i said, but i cant manage it !!! I find difficulties in this creation for the AR(2).

Any thoughts and help would be really welcome! Thanks in advance !

Anastasios